# How to add labels to UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have been searching around and cannot figure our how I can do the following. I would like to know if it's possible to create a static label in the selected row (as shown in this image link [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olVvo.png), "hours" and "min" labels), I mean I need that the label always stay visible and fixed.

Comment: Do you want to use dates with UIPickerView to select a time of day or a date and time? Or do you just want arbitrary text?

Comment: In the image link (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzD49LPzOAt4M0xEaDhFYjF1ZDQ) you can see what I have now, the repeated labels shouldn't appear, the main idea is that only one static label  should appear in the selected row